# Issue in Dev Express AspxDateEdit control in Page Load event

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am having issue in the DateEdit control, on Page Load event, I am setting the Maxdate property which is working fine.
the next line sets the DateEdit control (deDOB.Date = DateTime.Now.Date;)

But when I click on submit button to add the record to database, it always saves with current date.
For example, If I select the date two days before the today date, it just ignores it and sets it to Today date in the database.
I have tried to set the deDOB.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();

but the issue is not resolved

Plz help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Page_Load code overwrites the selected value every time. Specify the initial data when a page is being loaded for the first time only:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(!IsPostBack && !IsCallback) {
        //... DateEdit Customization Here
    }
}
```